# Titanium: Android back navigation via app icon in upper left corner

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have just started exploring Titanium.

I am looking for components/help to accomplish the standard Android sub-window back-navigation, where you have the app icon and back functionality in the upper left corner.

I checked the tutorials/SDK and kitchen sink project but don't seem to be able to find anything similar.

On their page with sample customer apps seems to be at least one app that demonstrates this type of navigation, which makes me think it should be available.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our Android/iOS application, we use the standard iOS navigation, but on the Android side we built our own custom header view to implement our navigation.  This view is added to the top of all other windows and/or main views.

We hooked the android:back button to trigger the navigation view's back feature as well, so we support both "standards".

Comment: Thanks. I see. Just starting out, I had a different idea of some of the concepts behind Titanium. I also got this answer: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154880/how-to-provide-app-icon-back-functionality-in-upper-left-corner-for-android